# Phrase for spending time away from your family or home doing something with friends

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that describes the time you take off from your home or family to do an activity for your own pleasure, but not alone, such as a beer at the pub with old friends, going to the movies with a neighbor?

"Own time" would suggest spending time on your own, which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: *me time* is an option, but may also imply spending time on your own.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with either
**Free Time**

> time available for hobbies and other activities that you enjoy 
>   [Free Dictonary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/free+time)

another definition

> Free time is time spent away from business, work, job hunting,
>   domestic chores and education. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leisure)

Or if wanting more formal then:
**Lesuire time**

> time available for ease and relaxation; "his job left him little
>   leisure" [Free Dictonary 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leisure+time)

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with ***downtime***

> time spent not working; free or leisure time
>
> [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/downtime#hbjv8K3pah2xQ62R.99)

Answer (score 1):

I think **spare time** or **time off** would fit your criteria.

Comment: Please provide supporting info such as an example from a reputable publisher even for short answers. Purely opinion based answers are not deemed responsive here.  I'm not the downvoter, BTW.

Comment: @PhilSweet Hi Phil, thanks for the heads up -- I'll be more detailed next time. However, I don't completely understand how any of our answers could be removed from opinion. We all speak and write in different ways, and often it's a matter of style.

Comment: @bejonsson Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how StackExchange works, then edit your post to improve it. Without evidence, it may be flagged as low-quality, downvoted, and/or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean special time for a man to spend with his guys then maybe 'guy time ' works here.

Guy time  n. When men have quality time together, and do "guy" things.

Comment: I don't know why people here like to give down votes to the others. Everyone here  mades effort searching for the possible answers to help the others get benefit from them and find the answer they look for.

Comment: It's part of the way the site works - people vote based on whether they think an answer is useful in the context of the question. Out of the ones currently posted on this question, though, I like your answer best and have given it a +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Me time** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/me-time)

> *mass noun, informal*
>   Time spent relaxing on one’s own as opposed to working or doing things for others, seen as an opportunity to reduce stress or restore energy
>
> *"schedule some me time when you get home"*

Answer (score 0):

Since OP said “but not alone”, I'm going to go with **hanging out**.